# I need different InstallShield prerequsite command lines for the same prerequisite

Tags: installshield

I have a batch file that builds 2 install projects. They each have SQL Server 2012 as a prerequisite but with different command lines (one is silent, one not for example). Anyway, I would like the projects to be built automatically without having to run one, manually change the prerequisite command line, and then run the other. As it is, there only seems to be one copy of the prerequisite settings - any ideas as to how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options. Neither are perfect, but I think I prefer the first.

1. Create two copies of the .prq, one with each setting. The quirk here is they either have to have different names (possibly good, possibly bad), or they have to be in different paths that you control, for example, with the [-prqpath](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/ISCmdBldParam.htm) parameter to iscmdbld. While the different names makes it easier for you to verify which prerequisite each build has, it may be more confusing for someone installing the prerequisite.
2. Install the prerequisite as a feature prerequisite, allowing you to use `[PropertyReference]` notation in the prerequisite's [command line](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/SetupPrereqEditorCmdLine.htm). Then set the referenced properties up differently in the builds that consume them, perhaps with the -z parameter to iscmdbld.

Note that if the prerequisite you are modifying has a download URL for an updated prerequisite, your changes will be lost when it downloads InstallShield's version, so in a situation like this you are encouraged to modify it to point to one that you host.